# How to remove nested list (of lists)?

Tags: list, haskell, nested

I would like to remove nested list from a list of lists. I'm pretty new to Haskell and found this difficult.

For example

```
[[a],[b],[c]] --> [a,b,c]
```

Comment: have you done any research on this at all? There is a standard, basic library function which does exactly this.

Comment: Lists are monads so you may just bind them like `[[1],[2],[3]] >>= id` to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Redu why overcomplicate it?

Comment: well if we're introducing monads (which I agree with @JosephSible is overkill here) then `join` is the easiest way (indeed the very definition is `join x = x >>= id`).

Comment: @Joseph Sible This is Haskell 101 level code. Besides if your flow is right to left this would be a much better alternative than using `concat` or `join` on the left of the whole code with `$` sign. Also.. `join` is fine but i wouldn't advise using `concat` since i think it is a misnomer. To me `concat` should be `(++)` operator.

Comment: `concat`'s name is fine, it is about concatenation. `(++)` is the binary version, while `concat` is the list version - indeed `concat == foldr (++) []`. Same thing as `max` vs `maximum`, or `(||)` vs `any`. Mind you, the comments to this question is a bit of a silly place to have this discussion.

Comment: And just to bring this full-circle, if the `Monad` typeclass defined `join` instead of `>>=`, the `[]` instance would almost certainly define `join = concat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely looking for the [**`concat :: Foldable f => f [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) function. This can take a `Foldable` type of `[a]`s, and return an `[a]` as a result. Since a list is a `Foldable` type, that thus means that `concat` can be "*specialized*" to `[[a]] -> [a]`. It will thus concatenate the sublists together into a list.

For example:

```
Prelude> concat [[1],[2],[3]]
[1,2,3]
```

This can work on other `Foldable` types as well, like `Maybe`, `Tree`, etc.